# Add rake tasks to a namespace without indenting?

Tags: ruby, rake

I'd like to add some rake tasks to a couple leves of namespace, but I don't want to have to indent my entire file to do that

```
namespace :one_descriptive_name do
  namespace :sub_name do
    # many tasks which all have to be 4 chars deep
  end

  namespace :another_sub_name do
    # many more tasks. oh, my poor eyes
    # and limited screen-width, woe is me!!
  end
end
```

Are there any other ways to put a tasks into a namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I know of two options

**Option 1**

Define your `namespace` with multiple levels

```
namespace 'level1:level2:level3' do
  task :my_task
end
```

**Option 2**

Define your tasks with the `namespace` in the declaration

```
task 'level1:level2:my_task'
```

Then there are a dozen other more crazy ways, but these seem to be cleanest approach

Answer (score 2):

Easy:

```
namespace :one_descriptive_name do
namespace :sub_name do
# many tasks none of which have to be 4 chars deep
end

namespace :another_sub_name do
# many more tasks.
end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby doesn't use significant whitespace in the same way Python does. You don't have to indent code if you don't want to.